# how to combine projection and pagination in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I have a document structure such as this:

```
{
    "name":"test", 
    "family":"test", 
    score:[
    {
        "point":3,
        "des":"blah" 
    },
    {
        "point":4,
        "des":"blahblah" 
    },
    {
        "point":5,
        "des":"blahblahblah!!" 
    },
    {
        "point":2,
        "des":"blah!!!!" 
    },......
   ]
}
```

now I want get the score section with pagination. how can i sort and project item of score with pagination?

Comment: What do you mean by *sort and project*? It is unclear what you are asking here. What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your sample data like this

```
{
    "name":"test", 
    "family":"test", 
    score:[
    {
        "point":3,
        "des":"blah" 
    },
    {
        "point":4,
        "des":"blahblah" 
    },
    {
        "point":5,
        "des":"blahblahblah!!" 
    },
    {
        "point":2,
        "des":"blah!!!!" 
    }
   ]
}
```

the following pipeline

```
db.getCollection('yourCollection').aggregate([
    // .. you may want to include a $match stage here
    {
        $unwind: "$score"
    },
    {
        $sort: { "score.point": 1 }
    },
    {
        $skip: 1
    },
    {
        $limit: 2
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "_id", 
            score: { $push: "$score" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { _id: 0, score: 1 }
    }
])
```

would return that output

```
{
    "score" : [ 
        {
            "point" : 3,
            "des" : "blah"
        }, 
        {
            "point" : 4,
            "des" : "blahblah"
        }
    ]
}
```

In order to modify the page number or size, simply adjust the value of the `$skip` and `$limit` stages to your needs.

[image: GIF showing working pipeline]

Comment: Well you have to adjust the collection name of course ?

Comment: @Navid_pdp11 Did you test it again with appropriate collection name? See my GIF